# Why doesn't Netbeans recognize `cbegin()`, `cend()`, `unordered_set`, among other C++ features?

Tags: c++, netbeans, c++11

My C++ application compiles and runs as expected in Netbeans. However, Code Assistance does not recognize terms such as `cbegin()`, `cend()`, `unordered_set`, as evinced by red underscores:

[image]

Code assistance does recognize `end()`, however. To no avail, I have tried going to Project -> Properties -> Code Assistance -> C++ Standard -> C++11. What else should I update or configure to let Netbeans Code Assistance recognize these terms?

Comment: Those are new C++11 features of the library. I would not expect all IDEs to understand them.... Make sure that the library that you are using has those member functions (in case it is actually *reading* the library)

Comment: Netbeans supports C++11 since version 7.2 (source is linked in my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make shure you use a Netbeans Version >= 7.2 because the the C++11 support was introduced in this version ([see "C/C++"](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/72/)).

If you already have set the C++ standard to C++11 in NB, you can *reparse* your procject:

1. Selcect your C++ Project --> right click
2. **`Code Assistance`** -> **`Reparse Project`**

---

**Edit:**

I tested the methods with the following code under **NetBeans 7.3 RC1** (using **GCC 4.7.2**):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main ()
{
  std::list<int> mylist = {5,10,15,20};

  std::cout << "mylist contains:";

  for (auto it = mylist.cbegin(); it != mylist.cend(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

With C++ Standard set to default this fails, but with C++11 (**`Project Properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> C++ Standard = C++11`**)it works.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of points I kept in mind when I started out with NetBeans and C++11

- Make sure its the latest(NetBeans 7.2.1)
- Do not use Cygwin to include the GCC libraries to compile your programs. Use the MinGW installer instead. Also make sure to 'Download the latest packages' from the internet when using the MinGW installer.
- After installation, make sure that the environment path variables are
  set correctly.
- Open NetBeans and go to **Tools-> Options**. Click on the C/C++ Tab and make sure that MinGW is being used as the default compiler.
- Right click on your project and select **Properties**. Select the
  **C++ Compiler** option and make sure that you have written **-std=c++11** in the Additional options space

Comment: the `std=c++11` flag is set in the makefile if you change compiler standard to c++11. If not you can *clean & build* your project again.

Comment: @ollo I have set **-std=c++11** flag in the location where I mentioned in my answer (which I think is on the G++.EXE) and code seems to work fine every time I use C++11. Is there anything else that you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes, it works. But this wont update the compiler settings visible in netbeans. The compiler setting do exactly the same like you do, but your way wont show this settings in the "c++ standard" field.

Comment: btw. this is only a cosmetic aspect, no functional. Both solutions work fine (or should do so^^).