# cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11' Netbeans 7

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans-7

I'm trying to set up C++11 in Netbeans 7.3, however I seem to have hit a wall. The error I'm getting is the same as in the title:

```
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11'
```

I have installed G++ 4.7.1 (which should support C++11) and have followed instructions this thread here:

[Why doesn't Netbeans recognize `cbegin()`, `cend()`, `unordered_set`, among other C++ features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675818/why-doesnt-netbeans-recognize-cbegin-cend-unordered-set-among-othe)

Here's the console dump:

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Nikola/Documents/NetBeansProjects/heap'
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/Debug/MinGW_11-Windows/heap.exe
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Nikola/Documents/NetBeansProjects/heap'


CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 654ms)

"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Nikola/Documents/NetBeansProjects/heap'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_11-Windows/heap.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Nikola/Documents/NetBeansProjects/heap'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_11-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW_11-Windows/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW_11-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW_11-Windows/main.o main.cpp
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11'
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_11-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Nikola/Documents/NetBeansProjects/heap'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Nikola/Documents/NetBeansProjects/heap'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I'm running Netbeans on Windows by the way.

Comment: Maybe try --std=c++11 or use c++0x instead of c++11.

Comment: Good call on the -- I think 4.7.1 had changed to c++11 instead of c++0x but I could be wrong, and have nowhere to test right now.

Comment: i forgot to mention, i'm running this on windows. how would i go about changing it to --std=c++11

Answer (score 0):

Change `-std=c++11` to `-std=c++0x`.